# Ошибка : нельзя преобразовать тип real к string

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

```
  floatToStr(c);
  StrToInt(c);
  writeln(c);
```

Компилятор указывает на вторую строку и выдаёт : нельзя преобразовать тип real к string
Мне необходимо перевести `real` в `integer`, а `с` на начале имеет тип `real`

Comment: По всей видимости у вас `c` - имеет тип `real`. Вторая функция принимает строку - а вы ей что передаете?...

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы перевести real в Integer, можно использовать функцию `Round` (также см. `Floor, Ceil`)

Между прочим, floatToStr и StrToInt - функции, они возвращают результат, а не изменяют аргумент.